# как объявить переменную типа typedef struct на си для 8051

Tags: c, define, 8051

Пишу библиотеку для дисплея на 8051(keil). Хочу сделать отдельный заголовочный файл с описанием всех цветов,  а потом использовать его в библиотеке и програме.
Вот файл Colors.h:

```
#ifndef COLORS
#define COLORS

typedef struct {
    int red,
        green,
        blue;
} color;

color   RED = {0xFF, 0xFF, 0};

#endif
```

потом в основной программе делаю так:

```
#include "Colors.h"
color col;
...
col = RED;   //*** ERROR L104: MULTIPLE PUBLIC DEFINITIONS
```

есть ли вообще какой-то красивый способ объявить константы для разных цветов и использовать их в аргументах функций прорисовки? (цвет содержит 3 байта RGB, т.е. в int не влезет)

Comment: Файл называется Сolors.h а тип данных color. Я не понимаю как инициализировать переменную этого типа. если я вставляю строку  color   RED = {0xFF, 0xFF, 0}; в основную программу то все работает, а если определяю ее в Colors.h то выходит ошибка.

Comment: colors.h : `extern color const RED;` ; colors.c : `color const RED = {0xff,0,0};`

Comment: ровно это и написал у себя

Comment: ¿Вы же в курсе, что при размещении определения переменной `color   RED = {0xFF, 0xFF, 0};` в заголовочном файле, оно будет попадать в каждую единицу трансляции, в которой будет этот заголовочный файл, да? Делайте геттер.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для такого рода констант обычно используют макросы.

Если компилятор поддерживает в каком-либо виде 32-х битный тип, то нормальным решением будет хранить цвет в нём:

```
typedef uint32_t color_t;

#define RED (color_t)0x00FFFF00ll
```

В противном случае, если компилятор поддерживает С99, то можно использовать макрос с составным литералом:

```
#define RED (color_t){0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00}
```

Для C89 нормального способа на вскидку не вспомню.

Comment: `цвет содержит 3 байта RGB, т.е. в int не влезет)`... Для C89 нормального способа - я привел два:)

Comment: @KoVadim, не влезет в `int` — может влезть в `long` или `long long`… я не знаю какой компилятор у OP'а — обычно компиляторы для контроллеров умеют эмулировать бОльшие типы, чем  разрядность… что касается способов, то для этой задачи я бы ни один из них «нормальным» не назвал бы: первый гарантированно приведёт к резервированию памяти под каждую константу и обращению к ней без встраивания, а второй, как минимум, к куче предупреждений на `-Wall` и опасениям, что компилятор не сможет нормально встроить значения (скорей всего сможет, но, сам понимаешь, что такие опасения — естественный рефлекс)...

Comment: у автора написано, что компилятор  8051(keil). А в документации написано, что многие операции с int/long приводят к библиотечным функциям...

Comment: @KoVadim, гмм... нуда... может для такого маленького контроллера хранить число в `uint32_t` будет и накладно и расточительно — может он и трёхбайтовую структуру не будет выравнивать, а лишний байт на пиксель не лишний... в любом случае, я к тому, что хранение 24-х битный цвета в одной переменной — более чем распространённая практика, а будет ли это столь же эфетивно на маленькой железке без кода, сгенерированного компилятором я спорить всё же не возьмусь...

Comment: да я не против хранения цвета в 4 байтах. Но автор вопроса то изначально спросил  совсем другое. может этот код у него уже написан и он должен его использовать. или есть функции, которые принимают именно такие структуры.

Answer (score 0):

Когда Вы пишите объявление структуры, Вы просто объясняете компилятору, что у Вас есть такая структура. Когда же Вы объявляете (declare) переменную, тоже - Вы объясняете компилятору, что есть такая переменная. Хорошая особенность объявлений - их может быть много, главное, что бы они совпадали. Но обычно переменные определяют (definition) - тогда компилятор выделяет сразу выделяет место под эту переменную. Если в хедер поместить несколько определений и этот хедер подключить в несколько с файлов (единиц компиляции), то компилятор с линковщиком будут вынуждены выделить несколько раз место под одну и ту же переменную. А они так не могут. Что делать? Есть классический способ.

В хедере пишете вот так (это объявление, а их может быть много!)

```
extern col RED;
```

а в любом c файле пишете

```
color   RED = {0xFF, 0xFF, 0};
```

теперь определение одно, компилятор с линковщиком знают, где разместить в памяти переменную и все ок.

Есть второй способ, писать в хедере вот так

```
static color   RED = {0xFF, 0xFF, 0};
```

в этом случае эта переменная не покинет пределы единицы компиляции и то же все будет работать. Но у этого способа есть один маленький минус. Теперь константы могут хранится в каждом файле, куда Вы заинклюдили свой хедер. Компилятор с линковщиком могут оптимизировать, а могут и нет. И если Вам дорог каждый байт (в микрокотроллерах так бывает), то лучше проверить оба способа и сравнить размер бинарника.

Comment: Большое спасибо! второй способ работает, а первый мне, видимо, не очень подходит, т.к. я хотел структуру и все определения цветов вынести в один заглавный файл.  А если я оберну хедер директивой #ifndef-#define-..-#endif у меня же переменные не должны расплодится при множественном подключении файла?

Comment: завернуть нужно, обязательно. а расплодятся в любом случае

Comment: прикольно, а минус то за что?

Comment: Похоже какой-то серийный минусатор забрел

Comment: просто видимо нужно добавить маленькое правило - даже если у человека больше 100к репы, но он поставил третий минус за сутки, отправлять на модерирование. Либо за третий минус брать одно очко, за 4 - 2 и так далее в степенях двойки либо просто в этом случае публиковать имя.